# I can't get Mercurial to serve under Apache on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, apache, mercurial, osx-lion, hgweb

I'm trying to get Mercurial to serve using hgwebdir.cgi under Apache on Mac OS X Lion.

I followed the directions listed here:
http://www.popitandrockit.com/2010/05/mercurial-server-on-osx-106-snow.html

That article is for Snow Leopard (I guess no one's tried to do this on Lion yet?) but it mostly works. I did make the modification that I did not use https because the machine in question is behind my company's firewall.

It says that I should be able to access a repository at `http://servername/repository_name` but that doesn't work. I can, however, get a listing of them at `http://servername/hg/`, where `/hg` is the `ScriptAlias` address. So I *should* be able to get to a repository via `http://servername/hg/repository_name`, but instead I'm getting a nice Mercurial page telling me

```
An error has occured while processing your request:

repository /Users/username/Documents/repository_name not found
```

Well, the directory is valid and there is a valid repository there according to Mercurial (i.e., `hg log` and similar commands don't error out)

On the main page I'm getting similar errors in Apache:

```
[(date)] [error] [client (ip address)] error accessing repository at /Users/username/Documents/repository_name
```

Were I to guess I'd say it was some sort of access or permissions issue but I'm not familiar enough with Apache or Mac OS X Lion to venture a guess as to how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This indeed looks like a permissions problem. On a standard Mac OS X Apache install the web user and group are `_www`, and you need to make sure these have read and write access. Also Mercurial complains if the hgrc file’s permissions do not match the user. There are two ways to fix it:

1. Make the repository owned by the Apache `_www` user. When you type:

   ```
   ls -ld /Users/username/Documents/repository_name
   ```

   It should show `_www` `_www` in the third and fourth column. If not, change the user of the directory:

   ```
   sudo chown -R _www:_www /Users/username/Documents/repository_name
   ```

   Note that if you change this, you should not access the repository on the file system from any other user, or else any newly created files will again have the wrong permissions.
2. Alternatively, explicitly add your user to the [`trusted`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#trusted) section in your `hgweb.config`:

   ```
   [trusted]
   users=username
   ```

   In this case you still need to make sure that the `_www` user has access at all. If you type:

   ```
   ls -ld /Users/username/Documents/repository_name
   ```

   It should show something like `drwxrwxr--` in the first column (the middle `rw` are important) and `_www` in the fourth. If the files are not readable or writable by the group, use the chmod command to make them:

   ```
   chmod -R go+rwX /Users/username/Documents/repository_name
   ```

   And you can change the group of your repository to `_www` like so:

   ```
   sudo chown -R :_www /Users/username/Documents/repository_name
   ```

Which of the two is preferable depends on your situation: if you’re trying to host your repository on a server I would say the first is preferable, it is simpler and a little more secure. If you’re trying to host it on your local workstation for convenience, the second is easier, because then you can still access the repository from your current user.

Note that for ad-hoc sharing it may be easier to just run `hg serve` on the command line.

I hope that helps.

Comment: This is probably the information I need, but I haven't been able to get it to work or throw the time at it. Since I need to be working on this system as well I've tried the second option but no such luck.